# postfix sasl "cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory"

Tags: postfix, smtp, authentication, sasl

I try to setup postfix with smtp authentication.
I want to use /etc/shadow as my realm

Unfortunately I get a "generic error" when i try to authenticate

```
# nc localhost 25
220 mail.foo ESMTP Postfix
AUTH PLAIN _base_64_encoded_user_name_and_password_
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: generic failure
```

In the `mail.warn` logfile i get the following entry

```
Oct  8 10:43:40 mail postfix/smtpd[1060]: warning: SASL authentication failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory
Oct  8 10:43:40 mail postfix/smtpd[1060]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Oct  8 10:43:40 mail postfix/smtpd[1060]: warning: _ip_: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: generic failure
```

However the sasl setup seems to be fine

```
$ testsaslauthd -u _user_ -p _pass_
0: OK "Success."
```

i added `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes` to the main.cf

This is my smtpd.conf

```
$ cat /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf 
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
saslauthd_path: /var/run/saslauthd/mux
autotransition:true
```

I tried this conf with the last two commands and without.

I'm running debian stable.

How can postfix find and connect to the saslauthd server?

Edit:

I'm not sure whether postfix runs in a chroot
The master.cf looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Fz38TcUP

saslauth is located in the sbin

```
$ which saslauthd
/usr/sbin/saslauthd
```

The EHLO has this response

```
EHLO _server_name_
250-_server_name_
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

Comment: Are you running Postfix in chroot?

Comment: Postfix is Running in a chroot.

Comment: So where is your saslauthd located? What does the EHLO show?

Comment: # which saslauthd 
/usr/sbin/saslauthd

my master.cf looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Fz38TcUP

Comment: is /var/run/saslauthd/mux made available in the chroot somehow? If not, there might be your problem.

Comment: I had the same problem, but when I ran postfix outside of the chroot it worked fine, I also added saslauthd_path: /var/run/saslauthd/mux in my /etc/postfix/sasl/smtpd.conf file.

Answer (score 11):

Are you perhaps missing the symlink from /var/run/saslauthd to /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd?

From my working system:

```
root@mail:/etc/postfix/sasl# ls -la /var/run/saslauthd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Dec 31  2010 /var/run/saslauthd -> /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd
```

Comment: is it normal for an update followed by a restart to remove the symlink? this happens from time to time on ubuntu 16.04

Comment: /var/run is a symlink to /run nowadays, which is a temporary file system that does not survive reboots; recent packages should recreate this automatically - maybe you have an edited startup script?

Comment: nope. all default

Comment: I'm out of ideas, sorry. :-(

Comment: I had to move this directory and create this symlink manually on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (bionic) after installing the distribution's standard postfix and sasl2-bin packages.

Comment: This seems necessary on Ubuntu 16 (and up) servers. Maybe also related to upgrading and not clean install issues. I modified the saslauthd startup script to recreate the link: `ln -sfn /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd /var/run/saslauthd`

Comment: This blog from 2005 sorted out my similar issue: http://www.jimmy.co.at/weblog/2005/12/05/postfix-and-sasl-debian/

Comment: Could you please explain or provide some url about why this symlink is necessary?

Comment: @MiSHuTka Postfix runs in a chroot jail in /var/spool/postfix, but saslauthd doesn't.  So the saslauthd running outside the jail needs to point at the path where postfix expects the saslauthd files to be.

Comment: @MiSHuTka Note also that nowadays saslauthd is automatically configured to point at the correct place, without the need for a symlink.  See `OPTIONS="-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"` in `/etc/default/saslauthd`.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen to me following an update and reboot, so it's still an issue (Oct 2023 Debian 11) and @paul-gear's instructions [here](https://serverfault.com/a/530346/1055615) fixed the underlying issue by restoring the symlink (thanks), but my fail2ban had decided in the meantime that my and my clients' IP's should be banned so our mail clients still couldn't connect. I removed and then re-added the `postfix-sasl` jail and all was well... i think/hope!